# wp_nav_menu not displaying the right way

Tags: menus, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a theme using bootstrap and now I want to display the menu adapting it to bootstrap... so I'm using the Upbootwp_Walker_Nav_Menu to achieve this, and also sending some args to the wp_nav_menu but the result is not what I expected.
This is the method which I'm calling on header.php

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                            'container' => 'nav',
                                            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse',
                                            'items_wrap'=>'<ul id="%1$s" class="nav navbar-nav %2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                                            'walker' => new Upbootwp_Walker_Nav_Menu()
                                    )); ?>
```

also I had to add a method to the filter on the functions.php

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args','specialist_nav_menu_args');

function specialist_nav_menu_args($args){
    if($args['theme_location']=='primary'){
        $args['container'] = 'nav';
        $args['container_class'] = 'collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse';
        $args['items_wrap'] = '<ul id="%1$s" class="nav navbar-nav %2$s">%3$s</ul>';
        $args['container_id'] = 'menu_primary';
    }
    return $args;
}
```

I was supposed after adding this changes, the menu will display correctly but if I see the html generated... this is what I see:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
   <ul>
      <li class="current_page_item">
         <a href="http://localhost/wp-musi/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-2">
         <a href="http://localhost/wp-musi/sample-page/">Sample Page</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

So first: as I declare thar the container will be a `<nav>`, then that will have the class `collapse navbar-collapse`. So what am I doing wrong?
I've read the documentation of this method [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) but it seems like not recognizing the parameters I am sending

Answer (score 2):

WordPress navigation menus won't conform to styling or coding changes if they are being built by default.

You have to actually go in and create the menu in Appearance > Menus and assign it to the menu location. After you do that, it should conform to coding/styling standards you set, as opposed to system defaults.